# How would I solve $φ(2^{100} · 3^{20} · 19^{200})$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't even know how to begin this question because solving the numbers inside the parenthesis is too high to be solved. $φ$ is Euler's Phi Function.

Comment: You don't mention what $\varphi$ is.  Perhaps it is the Euler totient function?  If so, do you know any properties about that function?  Perhaps properties related to products and to powers of primes...

Comment: Euler's totient function is a [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function)

Comment: I have reviewed some of Euler's Phi Function, but I cannot process how it works for exponent questions like these. I am not really familiar with the properties, this is my first time ever learning about this.

Comment: The totient function is not multiplicative except on products of coprime integers. That is, if $m,n$ are coprime, only then are you ensured $\varphi(mn) = \varphi(m)\varphi(n)$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer that's what multiplicative means.  If it's true in general it's called fully (or completely, I can't remember which) multiplicative.

Comment: Oh I see. My bad then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\varphi(2^{100}3^{20}19^{200})=2^{99}(3^{20}-3^{19})(19^{200}-19^{199})$.

Here I used that $\varphi(p^n)=p^n-p^{n-1}$ and that $\varphi$ is multiplicative.

Comment: This simplifies to $2^{101}3^{21}19^{199}$.

Comment: @Bernard That it does.

Comment: @Bernard How would it simplify to that if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @Varister: I factor  out $3^{19}$, obtaining $3^{19}\cdot 2$,  and $19^{199}$, obtaining  $19^{199}\cdot18=2\cdot 3^2\cdot19^{199} $. Alternatively, you can know the formula for $\varphi(p^n)$ in the form $p^{n-1}(p-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

A couple of properties of note, on the premise this is in reference to [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function):

- Whenever $m,n$ are coprime, $\varphi(mn)=\varphi(m)\varphi(n)$
- Whenever $p$ is a prime, $\varphi(p^r) = p^r - p^{r-1}$

Alternatively, use Euler's product formula by combining these. Let $n$ have the prime factorization $p_1^{a_1} \cdot p_2^{a_2} \cdot \cdots \cdot p_k^{a_k}$ ($p_i$ being prime for all $i$ and $a_i$ being positive integers). Then

$$\varphi(n) = n \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_1} \right) \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_2} \right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_k} \right) $$